# Write mapper output to a file and reducer too

Tags: python, hadoop

I am writing mappers and reducers for hadoop streaming in python. Mappers and reducers are running fine with out any problem. I want mapper to write output to a file and to reducer also. Is it possible to do this and how? If it is impossible i need to run mapper code alone, again. I execute as below,

```
hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.0-mapr-1602.jar -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=<q-name> -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx40960m -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=5000 -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=20000 -Dmapreduce.task.timeout=180000000 -mapper "<mapper-code-loc>.py" -reducer "<reducer-code-loc>.py" -input "input-hdfs-loc" -output "output-hdfs-location" -numReduceTasks 3
```

Any help here? Thank you.

Comment: the mapper and reducer out will write into tmp file which will present on /tmp folder. you can take a look using this command hadoop fs -ls /tmp

Comment: so my answer is. you can write mapper and reducer output to hdfs location. and finally you can download from there.

Comment: How do I find out this file, As I work on group id, I have l Lakhs of files in this directory.

Comment: you have add peace of code in your mapper and reducer, that has to write the output hdfs location

Comment: Example location: hdfs://master_node:port/user/yourname/mapper_out_folder/

Comment: once the mapper written the output , you have to use the below command to download all file : hdfs fs -get hdfs://master_node:port/user/yourname/mapper_out_folder/

Comment: final linux command to make all files into single file: cat folder_name/* >> file_name.csv